# run an EXE file and receive return value from it using VC++

Tags: visual-c++

Please i want to  creat a program/function in VC++ that allow me to run an EXE file and receive return value from it.

My EXE file tht i want to run is a console Application, it need two argument **Arg1** (String) and **Arg2** (Float), and return an **OutPut** (Float).

Something like :

```
OutPut = MyEXEFile.exe Arg1 Arg2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, this is work fine for me, i test it, and it work well.

This is the link of the page where i find the solution, i fixe some errors, and now it ready for implement.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10134/Execute-a-Console-Application-From-VC?fid=172409&fr=26#xx0xx

This is the exemple we need to execute. PS: this line is not a part of the our program, it's just here to explain the algorithm:

```
MyEXEFile.exe Arg1 Arg2 > sResult
```

The **"MyEXEFile.exe"** take two arguments (**Arg1** and **Arg2**) and return a value in the **sResult** Variable.

Let us program this exemple with Visual C++ using CreatProcess :

```
CString ExePath="C:\\MyEXEFile.exe";                     
CString arg1="2";
CString arg2="3";
CString sResult="";

CString strCommandLine = ExePath + " " + arg1 + " " + arg2;

// Call the ExecuteExternalFile function
sResult =   ExecuteExternalFile(strCommandLine);
```

This is the Function who will read the output of **MyEXEFile.exe** File :

```
CString ExecuteExternalFile(CString csExecute)
{
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secattr; 
  ZeroMemory(&secattr,sizeof(secattr));
  secattr.nLength = sizeof(secattr);
  secattr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

  HANDLE rPipe, wPipe;

  //Create pipes to write and read data
  CreatePipe(&rPipe,&wPipe,&secattr,0);
  //
  STARTUPINFO sInfo; 
  ZeroMemory(&sInfo,sizeof(sInfo));

  PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo; 
  ZeroMemory(&pInfo,sizeof(pInfo));

  sInfo.cb=sizeof(sInfo);
  sInfo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  sInfo.hStdInput=NULL; 
  sInfo.hStdOutput=wPipe; 
  sInfo.hStdError=wPipe;

  char command[1024]; 
  strcpy(command,csExecute.GetBuffer(csExecute.GetLength()));

  //Create the process here.
  CreateProcess(0,command,0,0,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);
  CloseHandle(wPipe);

  //now read the output pipe here.

  char buf[100];
  DWORD reDword; 
  CString m_csOutput,csTemp;
  BOOL res;
  do
  {
      res=::ReadFile(rPipe,buf,100,&reDword,0);
      csTemp=buf;
      m_csOutput+=csTemp.Left(reDword);
  }while(res);


    CloseHandle( pInfo.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pInfo.hThread );

  return  m_csOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Command-line arguments come in only one data type: array of C-style string.

Input and output come in only one data type: stream of bytes.

You can supply any command-line and redirection the output if you use  `CreateProcess` from the `<windows.h>` header file.  Other data types such as `float` will need to be handled the same way you would handle them in a data file.

Here is an example on MSDN: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I go with CreateProcess but i still can't receive the return value from the EXE file, maybe i do somthing wrong ? please can you check my functions, i just post them

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are going overkill.
For a command line app, the system command will do what you are looking for.

```
int status = system("MyEXEFile.exe Arg1 Arg2");
```

Comment: i test this command, but i get some code return and not the value returned by my exe file (consol application).

Comment: A possible workaround would be to write the status to a file and read it after it returns.

Comment: yeah i think about that, to write in a temp file and after delete it, it will work, but i want something with higth level, something professionnel, thanks EviTeach